# TWA url bar is not hiding in the android version upper to 10

Tags: android, trusted-web-activity

I have a TWA app in the google store. but when I install the app and run it, I can see the URL bar. this issue is on the android version upper to 10. how can I fix it?

Note1: Google console's SHA-256 is correctly in the assetlinks.json file.
Note2: My base URL is being with HTTPS
Note3: Everything working fine in the android version 8

Comment: I can attest that I have the same issue: URL bar shows on the TWA (without anthing, just an empty bar) but not on PWA... As in your case, everything seems fine with my assetlinks.json, according to [this tool](https://developers.google.com/digital-asset-links/tools/generator)